# How do I access the new Oculus Browser in the Samsung Gear VR?

Tags: samsung, browser, samsung-gear-vr

I've come across a lot of news articles, like [this one](https://www.wired.com/2017/03/gear-vr-just-took-huge-leap-forward-thanks-oculus/) and [this one](https://uploadvr.com/major-gear-vr-updates-web-browser-new-home-70-games-way/), which say that the newly updated "Oculus Home" interface for the Samsung Gear VR headset comes with a built-in new web browser that's superior to the "Samsung Internet" browser which was the default way to browse the web in Gear VR until now.

My question is, how do you access this built-in web browser?  I have noticed other changes in the updated Oculus Home interface, like the ability to create Avatars and the "Hey Oculus" voice control feature.  But I don't see a built-in Oculus web-browser anywhere.  There's just the old "Samsung Internet" app.  Is the Oculus browser something you need to install separately?

EDIT: [Here](https://www.oculus.com/blog/mobile-vr-is-better-than-ever?ref=producthunt) is what Oculus itself says:

> **Navigate the Web in VR with the Oculus Browser** 
>   The Oculus Browser launches today on Gear VR. A fully native app that renders incredibly sharp video, images, and text in Gear VR, the new browser lets you search the web directly from Home.
>
> Using the keyboard, navigate to your favorite sites like Facebook, Instagram, and YouTube just like you would on a desktop. The browser brings 2D and most 360 video content right into Oculus Home, with all the benefits of our newly built experience.

But I'm not sure where this "Oculus Browser" and "keyboard" are located.

Comment: looks like it might not be released yet.  The first article says the new gear doesn't ship till the 21st.. it would make sense that that's when they ship the new software too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the new Oculus Browser is out, however no clear documentation has been given from Samsung support website, fortunately a few workarounds are available:

Possible fixes for launching Oculus Browser:

**1. Uninstalling and re installing the software.**

Users have suggested to use the following order when uninstalling: (Gear VR service, Updates Gear setup, Gear VR video, Oculus, Oculus home and Oculus system activities)

After that reinstalling the software to make sure all latest updates are received.

Some instructions have been described here: [Samsung Internet](https://webvr.rocks/samsung_internet)

- Search and install Samsung Internet browser from the Oculus Gear VR Store
- launch the Samsung internet browser from your GearVR Library
- Navigate to a WebVR-compatible site
- Accept the option to enable WebVR.

**2. 3rd party apps**

You can try third party apps like [Launch Oculus browser 1.01](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.machenmusik.launchoculusbrowser&hl=en) developed by *muchenmusik*.
The authour claims it is capable of launching the new Oculus Browser on GearVR compatible phones

**3. Tweaking the hardware setup**

Some users described here: [How to fix Gear VR not launching when phone is plugged in?](https://forums.oculus.com/community/discussion/36104/how-to-fix-gear-vr-not-launching-when-phone-is-plugged-in) have complained of related issues with the browser especially when plugging in,
and a simple fix was to remove the connector on the GearVR and then putting it back. Check if it works.

Hope this helps

References (some included in text)

1. [SOLVED - VR application closes "unexpectedly" whenever I put the headset on.](https://forums.oculus.com/vip/discussion/32120/solved-vr-application-closes-unexpectedly-whenever-i-put-the-headset-on)

Answer (score 0):

In oculus home just look at the bottom of the main menu a tab says internet, click on that and that's it.